# Number Extraction from String - VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, numbers, information-extraction

I have a list of about 7000 records that are strings with numbers in them. I need to pull out all of the numbers, especially those that are preceded with a "(", "#" or "S ". The idea is that we need the ticket numbers pulled so we can analyze how many issues exist for each type of ticket. Below is the code I've written. I think an array might be better, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get that to work, so right now, it's looping through each character in each row and if the character is numeric, it starts to copy and paste the numbers in the next column until the characters are no longer numeric. It puts each set of numbers in a new column until it finishes all characters in the row.

The issue is that it is taking extremely long. Last time I let it go all the way, it took over an hour. Recently, when I make changes, I let it go for about 10 minutes and then stop it, and its completed about 1200 records. Each row could contain up to 100 characters, but most are closer to 30.

Is there any way to speed up the calculation?

```
  Sub findNumbers1()

    Dim v As Integer, Length As Long, str As String, i As Long, r As Range, 
    lastRow As Long, nextCol, nextRow As Long, result, ArrayResult As String, ws 
    As Worksheet

nextRow = 0
nextCol = 0
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = ws.Range("A2:A6885")

 nextRow = 1
For Each cell In r

str = cell.Value
Length = Len(str)
i = 1
nextCol = 2
nextRow = nextRow + 1

    Do Until i > Length
         If Mid(cell.Value, i, 1) = "(" Then

                    If IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)) Then
                        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1))
                            result = Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)
                            ArrayResult = ArrayResult + result
                            ws.Cells(nextRow, nextCol).Value = ArrayResult
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        ArrayResult = ""
                        nextCol = nextCol + 1
                     Else
                        nextCol = ws.Cells(nextRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                    End If
        End If

        If Mid(cell.Value, i, 1) = "#" Then

                    If IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)) Then
                        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1))
                            result = Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)
                            ArrayResult = ArrayResult + result
                            ws.Cells(nextRow, nextCol).Value = ArrayResult
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        ArrayResult = ""
                        nextCol = nextCol + 1
                    Else
                        nextCol = ws.Cells(nextRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                    End If
        End If

        If Mid(cell.Value, i, 1) = "S " Then

                    If IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)) Then
                        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1))
                            result = Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)
                            ArrayResult = ArrayResult + result
                            ws.Cells(nextRow, nextCol).Value = ArrayResult
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        ArrayResult = ""
                        nextCol = nextCol + 1
                     Else
                        nextCol = ws.Cells(nextRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                    End If
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    ArrayResult = ""
    nextCol = nextCol + 1
Next cell

result = ""
ArrayResult = ""

Call pasteNoITMS

ws.ShowAllData

End Sub


Sub findNumbers2()
'pull all numbers from remaining applications after findnumbers1 runs.

Dim v As Integer, Length As Long, str As String, i As Long, r As Range, lastRow As Long, nextCol, nextRow As Long, result, ArrayResult As String, ws As Worksheet
result = ""
ArrayResult = ""
nextRow = 0
nextCol = 0
Set ws = Worksheets("2ndPull")
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = ws.Range("A2:A2000")




 nextRow = 1
For Each cell In r

str = cell.Value
Length = Len(str)
i = 1
nextCol = 2
nextRow = nextRow + 1
ArrayResult = ""

    Do Until i > Length

                    If IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)) Then
                        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1))
                            result = Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, 1)
                            ArrayResult = ArrayResult + result
                            ws.Cells(nextRow, nextCol).Value = ArrayResult
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        ArrayResult = ""
                        nextCol = nextCol + 1
                     Else
                        nextCol = ws.Cells(nextRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                    End If

    i = i + 1
    Loop
    ArrayResult = ""
    nextCol = nextCol + 1
Next cell

result = ""
ArrayResult = ""

Call sortPulled

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the number of digits uniform (ie. always 7 digits)? If so, regular expressions will murder this task for you. If not, please provide more details about what the data looks like.

Comment: If you have already functioning code this would be a better question to post to the Code Review Community. For general tips check out [this link](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx).

Comment: Try to toggle [screen updating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-screenupdating-property-excel)

Comment: Thanks everyone. @BerticusMaximus, I appreciate the tip about the Review Community. I don't use SO often, but I will do that next time.

Comment: Please see below for some sample data:   

VSDN (22542) - NA and Mobile (23468)
SMART - Material Trigger (SMART) (11417)
 Smart (19221), vid(20703), (12569), DRIVE (20184), Data (13742)

Comment: @Vegard not always unfortunately.... they can be 1 number, up to 5. However, 5 is the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important improvement you can make is to minimize interactions with the range

You could also narrow the search to only the cases you need: (, #, S

Something like this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub findNumbers2()
    Const DELIMS = "(, #, S, , Test"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, lr As Long, allFound As Long, nxt As Long
    Dim ur As Variant, ubR As Long, ubC As Long, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim delim As Variant, dMax As Long, found As Long, result As Variant, t As Double

    t = Timer '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    delim = Split(DELIMS, ","): dMax = UBound(delim)
    For i = 0 To dMax
        If Len(delim(i)) > 0 Then
            If Len(delim(i)) > 1 Then delim(i) = Trim(delim(i))
        End If
    Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws.UsedRange
        ur = .Value2
        lc = .Columns.Count
        lr = .Rows.Count
    End With
    ubR = UBound(ur, 1): ubC = UBound(ur, 2)

    result = ws.UsedRange.Offset(0, lc + 1)
    For r = 1 To ubR
        For c = 1 To ubC
            For i = 0 To dMax
                found = InStr(ur(r, c), delim(i))
                If found > 0 Then
                    nxt = found
                    Do
                        found = Val(Mid(ur(r, c), nxt + 1))
                        If found > 0 Then
                            allFound = allFound + 1
                            result(r, c) = result(r, c) & found & ", "
                        End If
                        nxt = InStr(nxt + 1, ur(r, c), delim(i))
                    Loop While nxt > 0
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    ws.UsedRange.Offset(0, lc + 1).Value2 = result: 'ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Debug.Print "Rows: " & lr & "; duration: " & Format(Timer - t, "#,###.00") & " secs"
End Sub
```

---

Test results with 7 columns of data, each cell containing one or more numbers:

> ```
> Rows: 100,001; duration:  5.77 secs
> Rows: 500,005; duration: 28.25 secs
> ```

Comment: This was certainly helpful! And it works, however, some lines of my data have multiple sets of numbers, separated by letters. Like this: "EDPS - (18728);EPDF - Enterprise PDF (19636) - Informational". So I need to figure out how to run the loop multiple times within the row.

Comment: oh! I can put each string of characters in their own cell and run it... It still takes about 15 seconds, but it's much better than before!

Comment: Ah but that doesn't find anything that is just numbers... such as "Marketing & Pricing 22749".

Comment: I updated it so you can use a space as a delimiter as well, and if any cells contain multiple delimiters **it will extract all numbers after all delimiters**, but if there are multiple numbers separated by a space it will concatenate the numbers, so out of this text: ""Marketing & Pricing 111 222 333" you will get 111222333

Comment: That works quite well! Thanks Paul. One question; the array... it saves each value onto a new line. I can see this at the bottom, and it makes sense. Is there a way to save each line's value in the same row, but different columns? For example, if the algorithm had 3 values, put it in columns 2, 3, 4? I'm assuming there are some limitations with arrays... The reason I ask is that some of the strings have random values like dates, server names, etc. that we don't want. The idea would be that we can look at the outcome and do a quick visual comparison to make sure the values that show accurate.

Comment: Just saying, there is zero obligation here. I appreciate all you've done so far. I've been manipulating it on my own over here trying to be creative, but my forte is baking, not macros. :)

Comment: I made the update - the resulting cells will be in the same row they're found; if multiple numbers are in the same cell, the resulting cell will have them separated by comma. It's probably not covering all your cases but you can add more delimiters as needed. It processed 100 K rows in about 7 seconds

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the code place:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Then again at the end (before anything closes) place:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This will surely speed up the process as it will eliminate the need to show you what its doing.  Rewriting it in a more efficient manner would be ideal, but this may help speed it up to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid accessing `cell.Value` for every character. Just read every cell value only once - you assign it already to the variable `str`. Replacing the `mid(cell.value, i, 1)`-statements by `mid(str, i, 1)` (and similar) should speed up the routine dramatically.